# What is the format of this hex timestamp from the Amazon SES message ID?

Tags: parsing, timestamp, hex, amazon-ses

Amazon SES message IDs are in the following format:

`01020170c41acd6e-89acae55-6245-4d89-86ca-0a177e59e737-000000`

This seems to consist of 3 distinct parts

1. `01020170c41acd6e` appears to be some sort of hex timestamp. The difference between two timestamps is the time elapsed in milliseconds but it doesn't seem to begin at epoch
2. `c2daf94a-f258-4d59-8fdb-a5512d4c7638` is clearly a standard version 4 UUID
3. `000000` remains the same for first sending and I assume is incremented for redelivery attempts

I have a need to generate a 'fake' message ID in some scenarios. It is trivial to fake 2 and 3 above however I cannot seem to deduce what the format of the timestamp above is. Here are some further examples with corresponding approximate times:

- 01020170c450e280 - Mar 10, 2020 at 12:00:00.190
- 01020170c44c2e6a - Mar 10, 2020 at 11:54:51.987
- 01020170c0e30119 - Mar 09, 2020 at 20:01:07.407

What format is this timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking your first example of `01020170c450e280`, the string can be split into `01020` and `170c450e280`.

`170c450e280 hex` == `1583841600128 dec` == `2020-03-10T12:00:00.128Z`.

However, I'm afraid that the `01020` prefix remains a mystery to me.